# Background image in tailwindcss using dynamic url (React.js)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have an image url fetched from an API and I want to display it as a background image. Is there any way I can implement this with tailwindcss or should I use styles attribute?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think I have found a solution other than simply using a style attribute.

```
<div
  style={{'--image-url': `url(${fetchedUrl})`}} 
  className='bg-[image:var(--image-url)]'>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine.

Although it looks a bit tedious, it can be used to enable the background image on hover, focus, etc. In which the style attribute is incapable of.

```
className='hover:bg-[image:var(--image-url)] focus:bg-[image:var(--image-url)] ...'
```

This application of custom properties can be used for implementing dynamic values with tailwind like colors fetched from an API.

```
<div
  style={{'--color': fetchedColor}} 
  className='text-[color:var(--color)]'>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need a specific tailwind version to make this work? I can get the color example to work `bg-[color:var(--color)]` if I turn on jit mode, but I can't get it to do anything with images like in the example. The class is not found at all if I change it to `bg-[image:var(--image)]`.

Comment: @brense I tried it on the [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/) with different versions. Looks like you need to use version 3 or above of tailwind to make this work.

Comment: This does not work well with TypeScript as the property `var(--color)` does not exist for the style prop. I wonder if there is a solution without using `any` type.

Comment: @MosheG Sorry for the late reply. By doing `const style = {"var(--color)": yourColor} as React.CSSProperties` typescript will not complain.

Comment: This not working for me, my version of Tailwind is 3.1.x

Comment: @GeniusHawlah How exactly is it not working?

Comment: @TenshiMunasinghe It is not detecting the image even when I used color, same thing.

Comment: The style part is incorrect, it should rather be:
```html
<div
  style={{'--image-url': fetchedUrl}} 
  className='bg-[image:var(--image-url)]'>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: For example in Vue, here is my working example

```html
<div
        :style="`--image-url: url('/picture1.jpg')`"
        class="relative h-screen w-screen bg-cover bg-center bg-[image:var(--image-url)]"
    >
```

Comment: If found ```style={`--image-url: url('${bgImage}');`}``` works for me

Comment: Great solution. I had a challenge where I wanted to apply a background image to the before-pseudo using a Django and Tailwind.
this worked perfectly:
`<section style="--image-url: url('{% static 'images/backgrounds/about_us.webp' %}')" class="before:bg-[image:var(--image-url)]">`

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent a few hours on this. Can confirm this method also works in Vite, Svelte, SvelteKit and Flowbite-Svelte.

Answer (score 17):

I think the best solution is to do what you suggested and use a style attribute. Tailwind CSS doesn't really deal with dynamic data, but rather with class names to add predefined styles to your element. The best you could without using the style attribute is to conditionally add/remove classNames from an element, but that would require you to know the image URL ahead of time, which defeats the purpose of getting it from an API.

I would do:

```
style={{backgroundImage: `url(${fetchedImgSrc})`}}
```

Edit:
It looks like you can actually use Tailwind to do something similar to the code above as per https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image.
The code looks like:

```
<div class="bg-[url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your second solution. But looks like tailwind does not generate a class if it includes a dynamic value. So I shall stick with the style attribute.

Answer (score 12):

you can just use backgroundImage in Style

```
const bag2 = "https://via.placeholder.com/500"

<div 
    className = "someting"
    style={{backgroundImage: `url(${bag2})`}}

</div>
```

Comment: For me it was a pain in the ass figuring this out because the issue is fairly new and barely any sources of solutions, seems like I'll have to use the style attribute as well until they fix this.

Answer (score 5):

Even with the latest implementation of the arbitrary-values - it seems like it's not working for Dynamic URLs.
In my case image was coming from an API. If it is the case, stick to style attribute.

In the solution below - bgImage is a prop.

```
<div className={`justify-center  bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center rounded-lg`} 
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bgImage})`}} >
<!-- Children here-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this same issue in 2022, then this is what helped me with tailwind version ^3.0.23. I just moved the image to the public folder and used the link in my tailwind.config.js like so  `backgroundImage: { 'cover-pic': "url('/public/img/cover_pic.jpg')" }` where /public/*img* is the directory where I placed the image within the public folder, yours might different. and then called the css like so `bg-cover-pic` within my project, and that was all it took.

Comment: The OP asks for dynamic URLs, which means you don't know the URL in the build time!

Answer (score 0):

I just went to  html to jsx online converter https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm  the pasted what I copied from tailwind website -

```
<div class="bg-cover bg-center ..." style="background-image: url(...)"></div>
```

then I just copied my new generated jsx code-
`style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(/about.jpg.webp)' }}`

Answer (score 0):

The externalImageUrl can be url to any image hosted

```
<div
  className="w-full h-48 bg-no-repeat bg-cover"
  style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + externalImageUrl + ")" }}
></div>
```

Comment: Updating a style property during rerender (background) when a conflicting property is set (`backgroundSize` and `backgroundImage`) can lead to styling bugs. To avoid this, don't mix shorthand and non-shorthand properties for the same value; instead, replace the shorthand with separate values.

Answer (score 0):

Largest Contentful Paint element 26,040 ms

div.slick-slide > div > div.item > div.w-full

page url: [Etechbuy](https://www.etechbuy.com/)

any suggestion to reduce the Largest Contentful Paint element 26,040 ms

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stack overflow.  It looks like you have posted your question as an answer to a different question. Please delete it and create it as a question