# next js and tailwind css background image is not working

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to make dynamic carousel. I'm trying set background image but it's not working.

the first way I tried :-

```
<div className={`hero h-[75vh] bg-[url('http://domainname.com.bd/${props.mainImage}')]  w-full overflow-hidden`} >
```

second way :-

```
 <div styles={{ backgroundImage:`url(https://domainname.com.bd/${props.mainImage})`}} className="hero h-[75vh]  w-full overflow-hidden" >
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't help you much if we don't know the surrounding code concerning props.mainImage

Comment: This kind of code will always cause problems since you are using dynamic URLs. Try using `next/image` with `loader` prop. That will work better I think.

Comment: props.mainImage is only one url path which coming from a API. its like /custom/Post/2022/07/14/pranerbangla-14072022152955.PNG this .. When I tried with <img> tag it works perfectly fine.. But somehow its not working as background image

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Background image in tailwindcss using dynamic url (React.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805041/background-image-in-tailwindcss-using-dynamic-url-react-js)?

Comment: I've already tried this way but this doesn't solved my issue. So I solved this issue using parent element to relative and children to absolute.

Answer (score 0):

The first try won't work because Tailwind CSS doesn't really deal with dynamic data but the second try works if you just change "styles" with "style".
Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).