# how to set background image using tailwindcss in nextjs

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I want to add background image of a section  but I got this error

this is my code

[image]

this is my error
[image]

how to solve this.
even i remove my code still same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background image in tailwindcss using dynamic url (React.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805041/background-image-in-tailwindcss-using-dynamic-url-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own background images by editing the `theme.backgroundImage` section of your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
   theme: {
   extend: {
     backgroundImage: {
       'heroImage': "url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')",
     }
   }
 }
}
```