# Difficulty mapping background images in React app with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I am currently working on a React app where I'm using Tailwind CSS for styling. I have an array of items (trending), and I'm trying to map through them to create a set of divs with background images. However, I'm facing difficulties with the mapping and setting responsive background images based on the screen size.

```
{trending.map((value, i) => <div className={`w-[240px] h-[100px] bg-[url(${value.thumbnail.trending?.small})]`}
                        key={i}>

                        <svg width="17" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.387 0c.202 0 .396.04.581.119.291.115.522.295.694.542.172.247.258.52.258.82v17.038c0 .3-.086.573-.258.82a1.49 1.49 0 0 1-.694.542 1.49 1.49 0 0 1-.581.106c-.423 0-.79-.141-1.098-.423L8.46 13.959l-5.83 5.605c-.317.29-.682.436-1.097.436-.202 0-.396-.04-.581-.119a1.49 1.49 0 0 1-.694-.542A1.402 1.402 0 0 1 0 18.52V1.481c0-.3.086-.573.258-.82A1.49 1.49 0 0 1 .952.119C1.137.039 1.33 0 1.533 0h13.854Z" fill="#5A698F" /></svg>                           <div className="">
                            <div><span className="text-primaryText">{value.category}</span><img src="" alt="" /><span></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    )}
```

I tried inline styling but didn't work.

Comment: What difficulties are you facing?

Comment: thank for helping me but this question dont answer to my qouestion

Comment: i have dynamic background images and i dont know how to write code correctly, i want when screen size becomes 768 px bg-[url(${value.thumbnail.trending?.large})] large instead of small

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353036/trouble-with-dynamic-color-in-tailwind-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue, it looks like they solved it

Take a look here:

[Background image in tailwindcss using dynamic url (React.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805041/background-image-in-tailwindcss-using-dynamic-url-react-js)

```
<div style={{ '--image-url': `url(${value.thumbnail.trending.small})` }} 
     className='w-[240px] h-[100px] bg-[image:var(--image-url)]' key={i}>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this partly answers my question, but when the screen size become more than 768 px {value.thumbnail.trending.small} shoud be large instead of small

Comment: Not ideal but it will work

`<div 
style={{ '--image-url': \`url(${value.thumbnail.trending.small})\`, '--image-url-big': \`url(${value.thumbnail.trending.big})\` }} 
className='w-[240px] h-[100px] bg-[image:var(--image-url)] md:bg-[image:var(--image-url-big)]' key={i}>
  ...
</div>
`

Comment: Thanks bro, all day try to solve this problem, i am very grateful to you

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind generates a CSS file containing only the classes used in your project. It can't recognise the dynamically generated class name you're using so doesn't include it in the output file.

You are trying to set a background image dynamically based on the `value.thumbnail.trending?.small` property. However, the way you are using the `bg-[url(${value.thumbnail.trending?.small})]` class won't work because Tailwind CSS doesn't support dynamic values in this way.

You may use inline or custom css which includes tailwind property. It provide a way to use its utility classes as CSS variables in inline styles.

Comment: thanks for answer, but when i try to style inline @media screen (min-width:768px) dont works

Answer (score 0):

You might achieve it with tailwind but that might decrease the code readability in the long term. Here is an approach that you can follow:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [trending, setTrending] = useState([
    {
      sm: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2252314/pexels-photo-2252314.jpeg",
      md: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/327178/pexels-photo-327178.jpeg",
      lg: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/668353/pexels-photo-668353.jpeg",
    },
    {
      sm: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2248523/pexels-photo-2248523.jpeg",
      md: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg",
      lg: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2252314/pexels-photo-2252314.jpeg",
    },
  ]);
  const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState("sm");

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      let size;
      if (window.innerWidth < 320) {
        size = "sm";
      } else if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        size = "md";
      } else {
        size = "lg";
      }
      setScreenSize(size);
    };

    handleResize(); //Just for initial calculation
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    //Cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Current screen size: {screenSize}</h1>
      {trending.map((value, i) => (
        <div
          style={{
            height: "300px",
            width: "100%",
            backgroundImage: `url(${value[screenSize]})`,
            backgroundSize: "cover",
          }}
          key={i}
        >
          Some content
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

There are some third-party libraries as well that help you detect the screen size change but anyways, this is a really straightforward way you can work with.

Here is an implementation for the same: https://hyxnrc.csb.app/ :)

Comment: first of all, thanks for answering, but your way is very complex and i don't like it

Comment: If that's the case, then you might consider using some third-party libraries.

Comment: Also, its not always a very good idea to use libraries to make your code smaller as it can drastically increase your bundle size (if that matters). Best of luck

Comment: thanks bro trying to solve this problem